# Images in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I can't figure out how to go about resizing images within CSS Grid.

I don't mind if the image is clipped at all but I would like my aside item to resize the image so that it shrinks/grows to fill the item as best as possible as the webpage is resized.

The grid layout is adjusting with `@media (min-width: 600px)  { /* tablet */` and `@media (min-width: 1600px)  { /* desktop */`.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="./getting-started.html">Getting Started</a>
      <a href="./tracks.html">Tracks</a>
      <a href="./contact-us.html">Contact Us</a>
    </header>
    <main>Content</main>
    <advert>Advert</advert>
    <aside>
      <img src="https://jagrotax.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/mojo-tyres-rotax-max.jpg" alt="Mojo Kart Tyre list">
    </aside>
    <footer>Maximilian Crosby ©</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.container  {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 8% 10% 70% 10% 2%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: /* mobile */
    "header"
    "advert"
    "main"
    "aside"
    "footer";
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  min-height: 1000px;
  background: #BCF9FF;
  text-align: center;
}

header  {
  background: #A6CFFF;
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 26px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 40px 0px;
}

main  {
  background: #A6CFFF;
  grid-area: main;
}

advert  {
  background: #A6CFFF;
  grid-area: advert;
}

aside  {
  background: #A6CFFF;
  grid-area: aside;
}

footer  {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need to add this to your css:

```
aside img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
```

The Img inside your aside need to use 100% of the space (inside the aside area) that's why you need the width and the height to be 100%. Also by using the object-fit: cover, the img will preserve the aspect ratio.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cisco336/n5dzte8m/

Comment: Also how would I be able to change the image when the webage is using a different @media (min-width: ***px) ?

Comment: I think in this case you could use some JavaScript to change your image src depending on the width.